# How to define a new Charset in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

in Taiwan we have a character encoding called "Unicode At One (UAO)", which is an extension to BIG-5 but is not supported by Java and Android.
The code page is in http://moztw.org/docs/big5/table/uao241-b2u.txt

My question is, how can I build a String object with byte array data, using this Charset?
I guess I will extend the String class and do something in it, but I have no idea how to create a new Charset.

Comment: Why doesn't UTF-8 work for you?

Comment: Can you provide some other source of reference on this encoding? I can't seem to find anything relevant under the name "Unicode Completion".

Comment: Lukas: Because the texts aren't encoded by UTF-8, and I want to convert them into UTF-8.

Comment: moztw.org/docs/big5/ I found the formal English name is "Unicode-at-on" (UAO).

Comment: If/When you finish this, it would probably be a good idea to post it as a open source project (for example on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/)). I'm sure the Java community would appreciate it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add your own [`Charset`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) implementation by writing a [`CharsetProvider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html) and registering it via the service discovery mechanism.

You'll need to extend `Charset` and implements its [`newDecoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newDecoder%28%29) and [`newEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newEncoder%28%29) methods to return an appropriate [`CharsetDecoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) and [`CharsetEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) respectively.

Comment: Hi, sorry but can you provide some link of real samples?   I can't find the steps to implements, the API documents has steps but no description of how to do them.

Comment: @Romulus: Implementing a custom charset is a pretty rare task, so I don't think there are any ready-made examples and/or tutorials for it around. You might want to peek into the source code and check out existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some more to the answer by @Joachim.

A sample of a custom charset is contained in the book [Java NIO](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-nio/0596002882/) by Ron Hitchens. You can download [sample of Charset and CharsetProvider](http://www.javanio.info/filearea/bookexamples/unpacked/com/ronsoft/books/nio/charset/) from [the support site](http://www.javanio.info). Note that you have to make a file [META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider](http://ww.javanio.info/filearea/bookexamples/unpacked/META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider) that contains the FQCN of the additional `CharsetProvider` and put it into the `jar` you will make.