# How to read in scandinavic characters from US-ASCII text using java

Tags: java, spring, encoding, character-encoding, spring-batch

I'm writing Spring Batch program, that reads in file with fixed length data on each line and writes values to database. The problem is that this file's encoding is US-ASCII, but it has scandinavic letters that end up as ## or some other strange character. Scandinavic characters are encoded as 0x5B = Ä, 0x5C = Ö, 0x5D = Å. Otherwise it is uppercase US-ASCII text.

What is the best approach to read in this file? I'm currently using FlatFileItemReader that is provided with spring batch.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where text should have been encoded as ASCII but there were international characters being used. The solution for me was to read the bytes using the Windows-1252 encoding.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html) I see that FlatFileItemReader has a setEncoding method. Try the following:

```
reader.setEncoding("Windows-1252");
```

and see if it gives a better result.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the character set is ISO646-SE/-FI (7-bit) as described in http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/charsets-7bit.html. Java does not seem to support it out of the box. You could implement a custom `Charset`. I don't know Spring, but from the JavaDoc it seems you might have to implement a `BufferedReaderFactory` to be set on your `FlatFileItemReader`.

The following code might be a starting point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{ 0x5B, 0x5C, 0x5D });
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, new ISO646SECharset()));
        // Spring: set custom BufferedReaderFactory returning BufferedReader like above line?
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

/** ISO646-SE/-FI 7-bit character set. */
public static class ISO646SECharset extends Charset {

    private static final char[] b2c = new char[0x80];
    private static final Map<Character, Byte> c2b = new HashMap<>(0x80);
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < b2c.length; i++) { b2c[i] = (char) i; }
        // see http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/charsets-7bit.html
        // see http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/
        b2c[0x24] = '\u00A4';
        b2c[0x5B] = '\u00C4';
        b2c[0x5C] = '\u00D6';
        b2c[0x5D] = '\u00C5';
        b2c[0x7B] = '\u00E4';
        b2c[0x7C] = '\u00F6';
        b2c[0x7D] = '\u00E5';
        b2c[0x7E] = '\u00AF';
        for (int i = 0; i < b2c.length; i++) { c2b.put(b2c[i], (byte) i); }
    }

    protected ISO646SECharset() {
        super("ISO646-SE", new String[]{ "ISO646-FI" });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Charset cs) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public CharsetDecoder newDecoder() {
        return new CharsetDecoder(ISO646SECharset.this, 1.0f, 1.0f) {
            @Override
            protected CoderResult decodeLoop(ByteBuffer in, CharBuffer out) {
                while (true) { // TODO optimize, see US_ASCII class of OpenJDK
                    if (in.remaining() <= 0) return CoderResult.UNDERFLOW;
                    if (out.remaining() <= 0) return CoderResult.OVERFLOW;
                    byte b = in.get();
                    if ((b & 0x80) != 0) b = (byte) '?';
                    out.put(b2c[b & 0x7F]);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public CharsetEncoder newEncoder() {
        return new CharsetEncoder(ISO646SECharset.this, 1.0f, 1.0f) {
            @Override
            protected CoderResult encodeLoop(CharBuffer in, ByteBuffer out) {
                while (true) {
                    if (in.remaining() <= 0) return CoderResult.UNDERFLOW;
                    if (out.remaining() <= 0) return CoderResult.OVERFLOW;
                    Byte b = c2b.get(in.get());
                    out.put(b != null ? b : (byte) '?');
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Edit: In [How to define a new Charset in Java/Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960482/how-to-define-a-new-charset-in-java-android), they mention how to register the `Charset` by defining a `CharsetProvider` which should allow for `setEncoding('ISO646-SE')` to be used.