# Will the result of String.getBytes() ever contain zeros?

Tags: java

I have tried numerous Strings with random characters, and except empty string "", their .getBytes() byte arrays seem to never contain any 0 values (like {123, -23, 54, 0, -92}).

Is it always the case that their .getBytes() byte arrays always contain no nero except an empty string?

Edit: the previous test code is as follows. Now I learned that in Java 8 the result seems always "contains no 0" if the String is made up of (char) random.nextInt(65535) + 1; and "contains 0" if the String contains (char) 0.

```
private static String randomString(int length){
    Random random = new Random();

    char[] chars = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        int integer = random.nextInt(65535) + 1;
        chars[i] = (char) (integer);
    }
    return new String(chars);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++){
        String s1 = randomString(10);
        byte[] bytes = s1.getBytes();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            if (b == 0){
                System.out.println("contains 0");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("contains no 0");

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the Strings which you have tried and code as well. Provide minimal and specific code only.

Comment: Note that in several [standard charsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) the empty string `""` does *not* encode into a byte array with `0` elements. ASCII, UTF-8, and ISO_8859_1 all represent the empty string as an empty array. If you're seeing `""` encode to `{0}` you system is using some other default charset and you shouldn't expect your results to be typical.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check carefully. The empty string is also an empty array for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does depend on your platform local encoding. But in many encodings, the `'\0'` (null) character will result in `getBytes()` returning an array with a zero in it.

```
System.out.println("\0".getBytes()[0]);
```

This will work with the US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1 and the UTF-8 encodings:

```
System.out.println("\0".getBytes("US-ASCII")[0]);
System.out.println("\0".getBytes("ISO-8859-1")[0]);
System.out.println("\0".getBytes("UTF-8")[0]);
```

If you have a byte array and you want the string that corresponds to it, you can also do the reverse:

```
byte[] b = { 123, -23, 54, 0, -92 };
String s = new String(b);
```

However this will give different results for different encodings, and in some encodings it may be an invalid sequence.

And the characters in it may not be printable.

Your best bet is the ISO-8859-1 encoding, only the null character cannot be printed:

```
byte[] b = { 123, -23, 54, 0, -92 };
String s = new String(b, "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println((int) s.charAt(3));
```

## Edit

In the code that you posted, it's also easy to get "contains 0" if you specify the UTF-16 encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = s1.getBytes("UTF-16");
```

It's all about encoding, and you haven't specified it. When you haven't passed it as an argument to the `getBytes` method, it takes your platform default encoding.

To find out what that is on your platform, run this:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```

On MacOS, it's UTF-8; on Windows it's likely to be one of the Windows codepages like Cp-1252. You can also specify the platform default on the command line when you run Java:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF16 <the rest>
```

If you run your code that way you'll also see that it contains 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it always the case that their .getBytes() byte arrays always contain no nero except an empty string?

No, there is no such guarantee. First, and most importantly, [`.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) returns "*a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset*". As such there is nothing preventing you from [defining your own custom charset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5960482/113632) that explicitly encodes certain values as `0`s.

More practically, many common encodings will include zero-bytes, notably to represent the [`NUL` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). But even if your strings don't include `NUL`'s its possible for the byte sequence to include `0`s. In particular [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (which [Java uses internally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1)) represents all characters in two bytes, meaning ASCII characters (which only need one) are paired with a `0` byte.

---

You could also very easily test this yourself by trying to construct a `String` from a sequence of bytes containing `0`s with an appropriate constructor, such as [`String(byte[] bytes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) or [`String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-). For example (notice my system's default charset is UTF-8):

```
System.out.println("Default encoding: " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println("Empty string: " + Arrays.toString("".getBytes()));
System.out.println("NUL char: " + Arrays.toString("\0".getBytes()));
System.out.println("String constructed from {0} array: " +
                   Arrays.toString(new String(new byte[]{0}).getBytes()));
System.out.println("'a' in UTF-16: " +
                   Arrays.toString("a".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)));
```

prints:

```
Default encoding: UTF-8
Empty string: []
NUL char: [0]
String constructed from {0} array: [0]
'a' in UTF-16: [-2, -1, 0, 97]
```