# what would be an accurate mapping for x-IA5-Norwegian in java?

Tags: java, character-encoding

What would be an accurate charset mapping for charset: x-IA5-Norwegian in java? This charset (Charset: x-IA5-Norwegian) in an java mail parser is not recognized by java and throws

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: X-IA5-Norwegian
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fallback, you could use ASCII (which is the US variant of IA5), you'll then miss out on 0x23: `§` (shows `#`), 0x5B: `Æ` (shows `[`), 0x5C: `Ø` (shows `\`), 0x5D: `Å` (shows `]`), 0x7B: `æ` (shows `{`), 0x7C: `ø` (shows `|`), 0x7D: `å` (shows `}`), and 0x7E: `|` (shows `~`).

As far as I can tell, there is no such character set included in Java, and I couldn't find a library to provide it.

If you really need it, you could always write your own `Charset` implementation to map it. See https://wutils.com/encodings/x-ia5-norwegian for the character mapping, and [How to define a new Charset in Java/Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960482/how-to-define-a-new-charset-in-java-android).